# NHibernate and WCF Facility working together. Rhino Common Nhrepository outdated?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, wcffacility, rhino-commons

I have been looking for a good example of WCF and NHibernate facilities working together, (one session per web request, etc) but all the tutorials i find are dated 2009 and older. I am afraid i may lose my time trying to implement all this when there are probably better ways to achieve this.

The other thing i noticed is that Rhino.Commons.NHRepository was popular three years ago, but i can't find anything related to this assembly more recent than that. Any reason for this?

Anyone can point me on good examples on how to implement WCF and NHibernate using facilities?

NHRepository? RIP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be dead. I would suggest you to use one of popular IoC containers to manage lifetime of session and session factory. Almost all modern containers have integration with WCF including per request lifetime.

Comment: I am already using Windsor Castle and WCFfacility. I want to integrate my nhibernate (if possible using nhibernatefacility) with my wcf. I don't know if such a thing is possible. All i want is a recent tutorial that i can follow. Everything i have found so far is as old as 2008. :(